# Interval type without time in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals, period

I'm using PostgreSQL type `INTERVAL` in pair with `java.time.Period` type on application side.

What I want is to restrict insertion into `INTERVAL` column of all fields except year, month and day.

I know that there's `[ fields ]` part in [INTERVAL type definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html), but I can put only `YEAR TO MONTH` in it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_interval (
  col1 INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH -- only years and month allowed
)
```

And I need:

```sql
-- not a real SQL
CREATE TABLE test_interval (
  col1 INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH -- only years, month and days allowed
)
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
create table test_interval 
(col1 interval
,constraint col1_check check(date_trunc('day', col1) = col1)
)
```